# What the meaning of return [''] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please see this leetcode solution. In the function it returns [''] which actually return an array of answer. Could someone tell me what's going on there?

[The problem is solved. Actually it will return in the middle of the code.]

https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-invalid-parentheses/discuss/154272/JavaScript-BFS-solution

```
function removeInvalidParentheses(s) {
 let queue = new Set([s]);
 while (queue.size) {
 const next = new Set();
for (let v of queue) {
  if (isValid(v)) {
    return [...queue].filter(isValid);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    next.add(v.slice(0, i) + v.slice(i+1));
  }
}
 queue = next;
}
return [''];
}

function isValid(str) {
  let bal = 0;
  for (let ch of str) {
  if (ch === '(') {
    bal++;
    } else if (ch === ')') {
    bal--;
  }
  if (bal < 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
return bal === 0;
}
```

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: `return [''];` means to return an array, which contains one item, which is the empty string, if that's what you meant

Comment: something that returns `['']` is returning an Array, whose one and only element is an empty string - which would mean that `while (queue.size)` finished without `isValid(v)` ever being true

Answer (score 1):

The function returns an array with a single empty string if the prior code (line 7) does not return a result. It is simply a default value so that calling code sees some result from the method.

```
function removeInvalidParentheses(s) {
  let queue = new Set([s]);
  while (queue.size) {
    const next = new Set();
    for (let v of queue) {
      if (isValid(v)) {
        return [...queue].filter(isValid);
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        next.add(v.slice(0, i) + v.slice(i+1));
      }
    }
    queue = next;
  }
  return [''];
}

function isValid(str) {
  let bal = 0;
  for (let ch of str) {
    if (ch === '(') {
      bal++;
    } else if (ch === ')') {
      bal--;
    }
    if (bal < 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return bal === 0;
}
```